# I can not send a Request

Tags: java

I think my problem will be e laughti thing for you.

I have three classes called (CloudCommunicator, EnergyManagerJob and the Main)

My **CloudCommunicator** looks like that:

```
public class CloudCommunicator {

      private String _chargingStationId;
      public  void cloudCommunicator(String charginStationId)
      {
            _chargingStationId = charginStationId;
      }

      public  EnergyManagerJob SendRequest(boolean chargingOnGoing, boolean setCarConnectedToChargePoint, int setChargingStationDisfunction, float setMeterValue, String setUserId)
      {
           DChargingStationRequest dChargingStationRequest = new DChargingStationRequest();
           dChargingStationRequest.chargingOnGoing=chargingOnGoing;
     dChargingStationRequest.carConnectedToChargePoint=setCarConnectedToChargePoint;
     dChargingStationRequest.chargingStationDisfunction=setChargingStationDisfunction;
           dChargingStationRequest.chargingStationId = _chargingStationId; 
           dChargingStationRequest.meterValue=setMeterValue;
           dChargingStationRequest.userId=setUserId;

           try
           {        
                EVSEHeartbeatService_Service hbs = new EVSEHeartbeatService_Service();
                EVSEHeartbeatService h = hbs.getEVSEHeartbeatServiceSoap11();
                DChargingStationResponse response = h.chargingStation(dChargingStationRequest);

                EnergyManagerJob emj = new EnergyManagerJob();
                emj.allowedMaximumCurrent = response.allowedMaximumCurrent;
                emj.chargingPending = response.chargingPending;
                emj.powerOn = response.powerOn;
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
                System.out.println("Exception = " + e.getMessage());
          }

          return SendRequest(chargingOnGoing = true, setCarConnectedToChargePoint =false, setChargingStationDisfunction = 0, setMeterValue = 44, setUserId ="ich");
      }
```

and my **EnergyManagerJob** look like this:

```
public class EnergyManagerJob {


    public double allowedMaximumCurrent;

    public boolean chargingPending;

    public boolean powerOn;

}
```

So we will come to the Problem. In my main i have a while. I want to send the Dates of de CloudCommunicator to the server. And then I get an answer.

My **Main** look like this.

```
public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args){

    while (true) 
    {

        CloudCommunicator ccc = new CloudCommunicator();
        ccc.SendRequest (chargingOnGoing, setCarConnectedToChargePoint, setChargingStationDisfunction , setMeterValue , setUserId);


        DChargingStationResponse response = new DChargingStationResponse();
        System.out.println("\nDie Lade Station Startet: "  + response.allowedMaximumCurrent);
        System.out.println("Die Lade Station wurde gestartet: " +response.isChargingPending());
        System.out.println("Die Lade Station wurde gestartet: " +response.isPowerOn());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }       
    }   
  } 
}
```

Thank you for the Help. I think its not a big Problem but i have a blackout. xD

Comment: At first glance I see no [tag:mongodb] in here, but I'm not familiar with that so put it back if I was wrong. Also, what's the problem?

Comment: The Problem will be on this:                                       CloudCommunicator ccc = new CloudCommunicator();
ccc.SendRequest (chargingOnGoing, setCarConnectedToChargePoint, setChargingStationDisfunction , setMeterValue , setUserId);

Comment: Yeah but **what** is the problem? Do you get an exception? What is it? Or does it work but the results are unexpected? You need to describe your problem if you want people to be able to help you.

Comment: Oke Sorry. Yeah i have an exception  *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 chargingOnGoing cannot be resolved to a variable
 setCarConnectedToChargePoint cannot be resolved to a variable
 setChargingStationDisfunction cannot be resolved to a variable
 setMeterValue cannot be resolved to a variable
 setUserId cannot be resolved to a variable* thats my exception in the moment.  I have also make my Variable then the *message* was go to the server but my answer was not come. (Sorry for my English xoxo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile. The variables `chargingOnGoing`, `setCarConnectedToChargePoint`, `setChargingStationDisfunction`, `setMeterValue` and `setUserId` are simply not defined. In your `main` method.

Either define them (`boolean charginOnGoing = true`) or call `SendRequest` with the values inlined (`ccc.SendRequest( true, ... )`).